# PowerShell/PowerCLI how to display object properties

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I am using [PowerNSX module](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vmware/powernsx/master/PowerNSX.psm1)  to work with NSX and I would like to retrieve ESG syslog server configuration.

I have managed to find out how to get values using `$esgs = get-nsxedge` and then retrieve values by typing `$esgs.features.syslog.serveraddresses`

I've got an output of several IP's. I would like to display ESG name (it is retrieved from `get-nsxedge`) and combine it with retrieved syslog IP.

How can I achieve this?

Br 
wojcieh

Comment: Can you post your full code, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the best to include.

Comment: Combine how - what output do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Based on above description I guess that the information you want to combine is stored in `$esgs`. To select the name and the IP addresses you've to use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

Example:

```
$esgs | select-object -Property PropertyNameWhereEsgNameIsStored,  @{Name="IpAddresses";Expression={$_.features.syslog.serveraddresses}}
```

Hope that helps